# Mocking jsonwebtoken module with Jest

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, mocking, jwt

I try to mock with jest the verify function of the npm module jsonwebtoken. The function return a decoded token but i want to pass a custom return of this function my unit test.

I made express request that check the validity of access tokent before proceed to request. But I want to mock the moment of the token check to return directly the user value. And pass easily this step. I put you the concern part of code.

But typescript send me this error:
Property 'mockReturnValue' does not exist on type '{ (token: string, secretOrPublicKey: Secret, options?: VerifyOptions | undefined): string | object; (token: string, secretOrPublicKey: string | Buffer | { key: string | Buffer; passphrase: string; } | GetPublicKeyOrSecret, callback?: VerifyCallback | undefined): void; (token: string, secretOrPublicKey: string | ... ...'.

So the mock isn't working and I don't understant. I follow the mock axios step on Jest.io but it's didn't seem apply to jsonwebtoken.

Is everyone know what is the problem or how to mock this jsonwebtoken module on jest ?

> users.test.ts

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
    jest.mock('jwt')
    jwt.verify.mockReturnValue({
                    userId: String(member._id),
                    email: String(member.email),
                    permissionLevel: member.permissionLevel,
                    username: String(member.username),
                })

describe('### /GET users', () => {
            it('it should return 200 (Users List)', async (done) => {
                const res = await request(app).set('Authorization', 'Bearer').get('/users')
                expect(res.status).toBe(200)
            })
})
```

> Validation.ts

```
public isAccessTokenValid = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void => {
        if (req.cryptedAccessToken) {
            try {
                req.accessToken = jwt.verify(req.cryptedAccessToken, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
                next()
            } catch (err) {
                res.status(498).send({ error: err.message })
            }
        } else res.status(401).send({ error: 'cryptedAccessToken field not present in request' })
    }
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be because TypeScript "doesn't knows" that you've mocked the module, so you can try to typecast the correct type

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
const { verify } = jwt as jest.Mocked<typeof import('jsonwebtoken')>

verify.mockReturnValue({
  //...
})
```

or

```
(jwt as jest.Mocked<typeof import('jsonwebtoken')>).verify.mockReturnValue({
  //...
})
```

Comment: Not tested, but should be close enough

Comment: Hello, thanks for your quick answer. I test your solution, in effect it's solved my problem but we didn't want take an object in parameter of mockReturnValue.    

The error message said he wait a void response but I thought i can adapt the return type ?                                                    

 `const { verify } = jwt as jest.Mocked<typeof import('jsonwebtoken')>
   verify.mockReturnValue({ userId: member._id })`    


                        _Argument of type '{ userId: Schema.Types.ObjectId; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'_

Comment: There are multiple implementations for the verify method, and one of them returns void. ts is not being able to find out which impl you want to use. Try using `const verify = jwt.verify as jest.MockedFunction<(
  token: string,
  secretOrPublicKey: jwt.Secret,
  options?: jwt.VerifyOptions,
) => object | string>;`

Comment: I also want to mock the decode method of jsonwebtoken but it's giving null. Can you please check what's wrong here @Teneff? I am attaching the question link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74759568/testing-jsonwebtoken-decode)

Answer (score 13):

It took me a while, but I got this working, with a few lessons.

1. `jest.mock('jsonwebtoken')` needs to be used and it must be placed at the top of the spec file, just after `import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'`.
2. Doing this mocks all of the functions of jwt.  In my case I just wanted to mock verify.  This code resolves that (replacing (1) above).

   ```
    import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
    jest.mock('jsonwebtoken', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('jsonwebtoken'), // import and retain the original functionalities
    verify: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ foo: 'bar' }), // overwrite verify
    }));
   ```
3. I could then mock verify in one of three ways:

a) Leave it as the default mock (returning foo bar).

b) Using mockReturnValue, but I need to specify which overload I'm replacing (thx @Gabriel).

```
  const verify = jwt.verify as jest.MockedFunction<
    (
      token: string,
      secretOrPublicKey: jwt.Secret,
      options?: jwt.VerifyOptions,
    ) => Record<string, unknown> | string;
  verify.mockReturnValue({ verified: 'true' });
```

c) Using mock implementation:

```
 const verify = jest.spyOn(jwt, 'verify');
 verify.mockImplementation(() => () => ({ verified: 'true' }));
```

The annoying thing with all of these is that verify is now mocked for all describe/it in the spec file.

Comment: You can remove the mock from the jwt.verify function if need be by using the `mockRestore()` function. Note though that this will remove the mock implementation for everything in the spec file after you call the function. See [jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrestore)

Answer (score 2):

When using `verify` and returning the decoded token at the same time:

```js
jest.mock('jsonwebtoken', () => ({
  verify: jest.fn((token, secretOrPublicKey, options, callback) => {
    return callback(null, {sub: 'user_id'});
  })
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Jasmin's answer, I was looking for a unique mock for every test. My callback function only uses three arguments, on success it only checks email property. For tests where I want to see an error, I replace null with {name: 'TokenExpiredError'} which is the property my callback function checks.

token.test.js:

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
...
describe('Group 1', () => {   
    it('Test 1', async () => {
        jest.spyOn(jwt, 'verify').mockImplementation(
            jest.fn((token, secretOrPublicKey, callback) => callback(null, {email: 'cool@dude.com'}))
        ); 
        ... 
        (endpoint request and expect statements)
    });
```

And here is the code that this tests:

token.js

```js
...
const validateToken = (keycloakToken) => {
  const callback = (err, decoded) => {
    if (err === null && decoded.email) {
      console.log(`INFO: valid token - logged in as ${decoded.email}`);
      return decoded.email;
    } else if (err.name === "TokenExpiredError") {
      console.log("ERROR: expired token");
    } else if (err.name === "JsonWebTokenError") {
      console.log("ERROR: malformed token");
    }
  }
  return jwt.verify(keycloakToken, PUB_KEY, callback);
};
```