# Testing jsonwebtoken decode

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, jwt

I want to mock the data being returned from the decode of jsonwebtoken NPM package. I think I have also mocked correctly but it's giving `null` irrespective of what I try.

This is the part I want to test:

[image: code that needs testing]

This is the code that I wrote:

```js
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
jest.mock('jsonwebtoken')
// const { decode } = jwt
jest.mock('jsonwebtoken', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('jsonwebtoken'), // import and retain the original functionalities
    decode: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ aud: 'bar', data: { seller_code: 343 } }), // overwrite verify
}));
// decode.mockReturnValue({ aud: 'bar', data: { seller_code: 343 } })
// const decode = jest.spyOn(jwt, 'decode');
// decode.mockImplementation(() => () => ({ verified: 'true' }));

describe.only('EncryptData', () => {
    it('Should extract token', () => {
        process.env.REACT_APP_DEVELOPER = "Random value2";
        const res = TokenExtractor({ headers: { authorization: 'Bearer Token33432' } }, undefined, () => { })
        console.log(res)
    })
})
```

Comment: Why do you want to mock it at all? You control the value of the token, as it's an input to the function, so can make one that _actually_ decodes to the value you're trying to get a test double to return.

Comment: I didn't get you completely. I want decodedData to be controlled that's why i want to mock the result from decode.

Comment: It _is_ controlled, because it's a pure function of the header that you're passing in. Instead of `Bearer Token33432` pass a header with a token that actually becomes `{ aud: 'bar', data: { seller_code: 343 } }`, then you don't need to mock `jsonwebtoken` (and can also test that you're actually interacting with it correctly).

Comment: Ok I got your point and it's also working fine. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been answered by [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe).

No need to mock, I just needed to pass a token that would eventually give me the mocked result.

Try something like:

```js
 const token = jwt.sign({ 
    aud: 'Random value2', 
    data: { seller_code: 343 } 
  }, 
  'secret', 
  { expiresIn: '1h' }
);
```